# Python Loggin - Only log to file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Basically, I want to initialise a logger for each purpose, such that each logger will log to a file, but I notice that the content of log has been printed to console as well. I don't want that to happen, but I don't know how to adjust my code.

```
def getLogger(loggerName:str, fileDir:str,
              level = logging.DEBUG,
              format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'):
    """return a logger for logging
    somehow the logDecorator function does 

    Args:
        loggerName (str): name given to the logger
        fileDir (str): directory
        level ([type], optional): [description]. Defaults to logging.DEBUG.
        format (str, optional): [description]. Defaults to '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'.

    Returns:
        logger: [description]
    """

    myLogger = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
    myLogger.setLevel(level)

    myFormat = logging.Formatter(format)
    myHandler = logging.FileHandler(fileDir, mode='a')
    myHandler.setFormatter(myFormat)
    myLogger.addHandler(myHandler)

    # console only prints WARNING & ABOVE
    # ideally, what I thought is that if I don't not 
    # add a SteamHandler, the log won't even print to console at all
    # but adding a SteamHandler still prints EVERYTHING to the console
    # despite the level set as WARNING
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    console.setFormatter(myFormat)
    myLogger.addHandler(console)

    return myLogger
```

I have tried this:

```
mainLogger = logging.getLogger()
mainLogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING) # only log WARNING and above
```

but It won't work as well, still printing to console.

So I am lost in my understanding of LOGGING module, I am not sure where have I done wrong.

Example of using the code:

```
aRandomLogger = getLogger(loggerName = 'ProgressLogger', fileDir = '../logs/ProgressLogger.log')

aRandomLogger.info('This is an information, I want it to be log to file, but not on console')

aRandomLogger.warning('this is a warning, I want it be be log to file, and shown on console')
```

Turns out, both logs are saved to file and to console.

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Comment: Ok, I have provided an example of how I use the code

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem, your code works as expected for me.

Comment: Save this snippet in separate file and run it. Probably there is something else going on in your actual code.

Comment: Ok, now that I ran it I see that it is working properly, but it doesn't work for my project wide session run. But I don't know how to locate, or who has changed the config at which point, are there any ways I can overwrite this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been awhile, but I have managed to figure out the solution to this.

```
myLogger = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
myLogger.propagate = False
```

Setting `propagate` to `False` will prevent the logger from producing unwanted logs everywhere.